# Forgotten password emails and reset

Tags: passwords, kentico

I am trying to configure email when user clicks Forgotten password link. 
It seems that when user clicks this link password is reset. What I would like to have is have the existing password be send to the user. 
This is what I have. 
User1 has password Password1
User forgets password, they click on forgotten password link and they get this email.

```
You requested a password reset at mysite.org/logon.aspx. 
Your user name and new password are: 
User name: User1@email.org 
Password: ?caGXG=]
```

What is "?caGXG=]" is this a new reset password ?

This is what I would like to have. 
User1 has password Password1
User forgets password, they click on forgotten password link and they get this email.

```
You requested a password reset at mysite.org/logon.aspx. 
Your user name and new password are: 
User name: User1@email.org 
Password: Password1
```

I have looked all over and I can't find send existing password setting and do not reset.

I am using      v8.2.42

Answer (score 5):

This would be an extremely bad practice for many reasons. (E.g. if an account has been hacked the attacker could misuse the password to attack all victim's services that use the same password.) 
It would also be very difficult to achieve as Kentico by default stores only hashes of the passwords using SHA2 + salt. You'd have to store the passwords in plaintext. Please, don't do that and keep using the existing reset password functionality.

Comment: ?caGXG=] in my case is a new password or hash ?

Comment: a newly generated password